# jQuery find $.find('selector') versus $('selector') difference

Tags: jquery, find, css-selectors

I've got a question why these two code snippets are different.

```
$('#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1')  
//jQuery(a#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1 Default.aspx) Console output
$('#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1').text()
```

The code above returns : `Some link text`

But

```
$.find('#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1')  
//[a#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1 Default.aspx] Consolee output
$.find('#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1').text()
```

Returns

> TypeError: `$.find("#ctl00_DDMenu1_HyperLink1").text` is not a function

Does this mean that **`$.find`** return Array object `[]` and jQuery functions are not accessible?

### //EDIT

I've used jQuery 1.4.2 & used Firebug Console.

### //Answer found by practise

This code will return **jQuery object reference** and all jQuery function are accessible.

`$('any_selector')

    //jQuery(item1),jQuery(item2),...,jQuery(item-N) Console output
    $('any_selector').text()`

This code return **JavaScript Array object** so any function of jQuery cannot be applied to resultset. Even when resultset seems to be identical.

`$.find('any_selector')

    //[item1,item2,...,item-N] Consolee output

    $.find('any_selector').text()`

But we can do trick (weird trick) to wrapp js Array into jQuery selector:

`$($.find('any_selector_as_inner_select')).val()`

**//Thanks for help guys!**

Comment: You shouldn't be using .find() to look for elements with a specific id attribute. The ID should be unique per element. If you want to check for a certain suffix or prefix, then you may do that.

Comment: It's just a example of diffrence between functions how they works. Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `find()` lets you filter on a set of elements based on a selection you've already made.For example if you wanted to select all of the inputs within a particular form, you could write:

```
$('#aParticularForm').find('input')
```

It cannot be called on its own.

Comment: I think it can be called on its own but it seems odd:

 `$($.find('#aParticularForm input)).val()`

Comment: @r.piesnikowski oh interesting, I wasn't aware of that! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: $.find() function returns JavaScript array of matching objects so any jQuery function cannot be accessible in pure JS object. But wrapping those JS object inside $() affect good result. Cheers!

Comment: What's interesting is that `$($.find('#foo')).text()` and `$('#something').find('#foo').text()` will both work but `$.find('#foo').text()` will not.