# JQuery Mobile, find a specific input form on a given page

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here is the answer from another question: [jQuery find $.find('selector') versus $('selector') difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083183/jquery-find-findselector-versus-selector-difference)

The reason this does not work is because find() lets you filter on a set of elements based on a selection you've already made.For example if you wanted to select all of the inputs within a particular form, you could write:

```
$('#aParticularForm').find('input')
```

It cannot be called on its own.

How can I expand this statement to find specific inputs on a page? (Specifically listviews)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? What do you mean by it can't be called on its own? With this you can select one or more elements so I don't see the point of your question.

Comment: The text above is a quote from an answer found in the link, my question is how can I select an individual input on the page rather than selecting all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/93VFG/

Wanted element must have a unique identification, like id or class.

**HTML :**

```
<form id="aParticularForm">
    <input type="text" value="One" id="input1"/>
    <input type="text" value="Two" id="input2"/>                
</form>
```

**Javascript :**

```
var input = $('#aParticularForm').find('#input1');
alert(input.val());
```

You can even go further, because you are working with a jQuery Mobile you can have several pages loaded into the DOM and they can all have identical input fields, so to find elements only in a current active page you would use:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#input1');
```

Comment: you would want to find a specific li element inside a listview or a specific listview? Of course it will work but give me a context and I will create you an example.