# Jquery click to open modal returns " undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to open a modal on a mouse click but i can't seem to get it to work at all. Here is my code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Attack1Id").click(function () {
        var location = $.find("#dialog");
        $(location).dialog({
            title: "Dialog box",
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("FileTables", "Card")");
            },
            on: ('click', '.table a', function () {
                alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

It would seem "dialog" is the undefined function, but how else am i suppose to create a jquery dialog?

Update

Just for clarity this is my whole html page

```
@model CardSite.Models.Card

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Card";
}

<h2>New card type</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCard", "Card", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        <div class="text-box-for">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Attack1Id)
        <div class="text-box-for">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attack1Id)
        </div>

        <div id="dialog"></div>

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Attack1Id").click(function () {
            var location = $.find("#dialog");
            $(location).dialog({
                title: "Dialog box",
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                },
                on: ('click', '.table a', function () {
                    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
                })
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

--- Update ---

I just updated my code to look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Attack1Id").click(function () { 
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Dialog box",
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("@Url.Action("FileTables", "Card")");
                },
                on: ('click', '.table a', function () {
                    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
                })
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Dialog box",
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("@Url.Action("FileTables", "Card")");
                },
                on: ('click', '.table a', function(){
                    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
                })
            })
        );
</script>
```

and the modal works, it appears at the start of the page, i can close and then click on the input box and it appears again. But if I close the modal, re-open the modal and then click on view, it does two alerts, like it has created more than one... any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where is your libraries attached?

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI?

Comment: at the top of the html file

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Mc8CP/, any error in the network console?

Comment: none at all. I wonder what is wrong with it? :(

Comment: no just undefined function at this line "$("#dialog").dialog({"

Comment: I see that your jQuery UI library is custom...have you included all the needed resources for dialog right? Try include this instead: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

Comment: I tried to include "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" but dialog is still undefined :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some discrepancies between the use of `$.find` and `$('selector')`.

> This code return JavaScript Array object so any function of jQuery cannot be applied to resultset. Even when resultset seems to be identical.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083183/jquery-find-findselector-versus-selector-difference)

Have you tried using `$("#dialog")` to select the dialog instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Attack1Id").click(function () { 
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Dialog box",
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("FileTables", "Card")");
            },
            on: ('click', '.table a', function () {
                alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())
            })
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update:**

I feel your script reference is not called in your page. Try to replace script references with below code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Still getting the undefined function

Comment: Even with those lines at the top it still states undefined function :(